# What's the point of Spring Batch's JobLocator?

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I've created a Spring Batch application (together with Spring Boot). Configuring a Job works well, and each Job is executed at startup. The job configurations also show up in the database as expected.

To launch a Job with parameters, there are two options:

- Inject the Job as it is a Java Bean - works great
- Use JobLocator to get a instance of the Job - seen in several tutorials, but does not work ("No job configuration with the name [doSomethingJob] was registered")

So my question is: What's the point of a JobLocator if one can easily inject jobs directly?

Comment: With regards to your issue, are you actually registering your jobs with the `JobLocator`?  If so, which locator are you using and how are you registering them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `JobLocator` isn't for injection of jobs.  It's to locate an instance to execute.  If you have something that will be executing jobs dynamically (not knowing what job it will need to execute), you'll want to use a `JobLocator`.  An example of this is in Spring Batch Admin.  There, a `JobLocator` is used from within the `JobService` to get the requested `Job` to launch.

Wiring a `Job` instance into your class works well when it's predetermined what job you'll be running.  However, if you don't, the `JobLocator` is the way to go.